# Floating units with different heights on Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

An array of pictures of different high, and constant width. Necessary to fill the page so that they are tightly streamlined each other.

On jQuery so. There are 3 columns. The first step is to loading the images, and after the event onLoad, the next step - to move the image in the lowest column.

But angularJs this causes difficulties, cut and mix items are not that good at doing angularJs.

One of the solutions devised. Stored for each column of the array and a array for column of all the pictures. Field of each individual loading of pictures, send the event to the top, and the controller must choose the lowest column and paste the image in its array. But I have a problem with the implementation of this on angularJs

```
 <div class="container" ng-controller="columnCtrl">
     <div class="column" ng-column="column1">
       <div ng-repeat="imageSrc in columns.column1.imagesSrc">
           <img ng-load="$emit('loadImg')" 
                src="{{imageSrc}}" alt="img" />
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="column" ng-column="column2">
       <div ng-repeat="imageSrc in columns.column2.imagesSrc">
           <img ng-load="$emit('loadImg')" 
                src="{{imageSrc}}" alt="img" />
       </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

[Full example of solving this problem - Pluker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5j7gk2mkRoGLPUELxoKL)

Comment: Please post some code, what have you tried?

Comment: I added a link to  Punker, there is a complete working example. If you can help to do something better, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmtl:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="MainController as main">
    <div class="column" ng-repeat="column in main.columns">
      <div ng-repeat="image in column.images">
        <img load src="{{image}}" alt="img" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('MainController', MainController)
  .service('columnsService', columnsService)
  .directive('load', loadDirective);

function MainController($scope, columnsService) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.columns = columnsService.columns;
  columnsService.init([
   'http://www.myschool21.narod.ru/mountain/images/fr_1041.jpg',
  'http://wallpaperscraft.ru/image/92232/200x300.jpg?orig=3',
  'http://cs10573.vk.me/g24449285/a_e2f12ad0.jpg',
  'http://static2.gooddays.ru/photos/0002/6209/andorra_preview.jpg?1241084584',
  'http://www.comunicom.ru/images/stories/PHOTO-2013/MINI/3.jpg'
  ]);
}

function columnsService() {
  var service = {
    images: [],
    columnsCount: 3,
    columns: [],
    init: init,
    initColumns: initColumns,
    pushNextImage: pushNextImage,
    getLowestColumn: getLowestColumn,
    updateColumn: updateColumn
  };
  return service;

  function init(images) {
    service.images = images;
    service.initColumns();
    service.pushNextImage();
  }

  function initColumns() {
    for (var i = 0; i < service.columnsCount; i++) {
      service.columns[i] = {
        height: 0,
        images: []
      };
    }
  }

  function pushNextImage() {
    var image = service.images.shift();
    if (image) {
      var column = service.getLowestColumn();
      column.images.push(image); 
    }
  }

  function getLowestColumn() {
    var minIndex = null;
    var minHeight = null;
    angular.forEach(service.columns, function(column, index) {
      if (minIndex === null || column.height < minHeight) {
        minIndex = index;
        minHeight = column.height;
      }
    });
    return service.columns[minIndex];
  }

  function updateColumn(index, height) {
    service.columns[index].height += height;
  }
}

function loadDirective(columnsService) {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: link
  };
  return directive;

  function link($scope, element, attrs) {
    element.on('load', function(event) {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        columnsService.updateColumn($scope.$parent.$index, element[0].offsetHeight);
        columnsService.pushNextImage();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Live: http://jsbin.com/qunih/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Very grateful Navix, your solving exactly what me need.

It should be added to the service method for the loading pictures later.

```
var service = {
  images: [],
  columnsCount: 3,
  columns: [],
  init: init,
  initColumns: initColumns,
  pushImages: pushImages,
  pushNextImage: pushNextImage,
  getLowestColumn: getLowestColumn,
  updateColumn: updateColumn
};
return service;

function addImages(images) {
  service.images = service.images.concat(images);
  service.pushNextImage();
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kzVojQVR1qaCyZa07ReN)

and this module can be reused for the placement on pages of floating images of different height.